# How to add text above the legend and align item in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

attached is the image and is my expected results. I'd like to add the text Vehicle and Percentage above the legend and also align them legend text and the number. How to do this using Highcharts?

[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PX5hS.png)

[Demo](https://codepen.io/iosum/pen/bGZgzep?editors=1010)

```js
Highcharts.chart("container", {
  colors: ["#01BAF2", "#71BF45", "#FAA74B", "#B37CD2"],
  chart: {
    type: "pie"
  },
  accessibility: {
    point: {
      valueSuffix: "%"
    }
  },
  title: {
    text: "February 2020 Norway passenger auto registrations"
  },
  subtitle: {
    text:
      'Source:<a href="https://cleantechnica.com/2020/03/07/pioneering-norway-rises-above-68-plug-in-vehicle-market-share-in-february/">cleantechnica</a>'
  },
  tooltip: {
    pointFormat: "{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.0f}%</b>"
  },
  plotOptions: {
    pie: {
      allowPointSelect: true,
      cursor: "pointer",
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        formatter: function () {
          return this.point.name + ' ' + this.y;
        } 
      },
      showInLegend: true
    }
  },
  series: [
    {
      name: "Registrations",
      colorByPoint: true,
      innerSize: "75%",
      data: [
        {
          name: "EV",
          y: 68.1
        },
        {
          name: "Hybrids",
          y: 11.0
        },
        {
          name: "Diesel",
          y: 11.2
        },
        {
          name: "Petrol",
          y: 9.7
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  legend: {
    align: "right",
    verticalAlign: "middle",
    enabled: true,
    itemWidth: 200,

    useHTML: true,
    labelFormatter: function () {
      return this.name + " " + Math.round(this.percentage * 100) / 100 + "%";
    }
  }
});
```

I've tried using labelFormatter annd legend text but nothing fits my need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use title property within the legend.
Try this:

```
legend: {
align: "right",
verticalAlign: "middle",
enabled: true,
itemWidth: 200,
useHTML: true,
title: {
  text: 'Vehicle Percentage'
},
labelFormatter: function () {
  return this.name + " " + Math.round(this.percentage * 100) / 100 + "%";
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't say it's the best way to do this but it works:

```
title: {
  text: `<div style="display: flex";font-size: 10px><div style="width: 50px">Vehicle</div><div>Percentage</div></div>`
},
labelFormatter: function () {
  return `<div style="display: flex"><div style="width: 50px">${this.name}</div><div id="percent">${Math.round(this.percentage * 100) / 100}</div></div>`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of possible solutions to your issue. Let's start with the simplest one:

1. You can use a title property of a legend to put a text above the legend items.

API references: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.title.text

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xc9n2pde/

```
legend: {
 title: {
   text: 'Vehicle Percentage'
 }
}
```

2. You can use SVG Renderer to render a text above the legend. In this solution you have more control of the text position.

API references: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#text

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/f85a3kco/

3. You can create your own HTML custom legend. In this solution you can freely create a table in which you can have two columns. One for vehicle names and the other one for the percentage values.

Docs: https://highcharts.freshdesk.com/a/solutions/articles/44002324228